# multiple conditions + regex in awk command

Tags: swift, regex, awk, zsh

I'm using the following awk command to replace strings in a swift source file:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { old=ARGV[1]; new=ARGV[2]; ARGV[1]=ARGV[2]=""; len=length(old) }
    s=index($0,old) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+len) }
    { print }
' "$old" "$new" "$file" > ./temp
```

Trying not to edit commented out values. At a minimum, need to ignore lines that start with "//" but it seems possible to ignore inline comments (e.g. when the line is only partially commented like `"MATCH // <- Ok"` or `"foo // MATCH <- Not Ok"`).

Something like...

```
    s=index($0,old) && !($0 =~ "^//") { ... }
```

Sample Input:

```
old="\"Some \(value) with %@ special \n characters\""
new="\"some_key\".localized"

file {contents}...
    /// - Returns: "Some \(value) with %@ special \n characters"
    static let someValue = "Some \(value) with %@ special \n characters" // <-- This should change

    static let otherValue = "This line does NOT change" // "Some \(value) with %@ special \n characters"
```

Expected Output:

```
    /// - Returns: "Some \(value) with %@ special \n characters"
    static let someValue = "some_key".localized // <-- This should change

    static let otherValue = "This line does NOT change" // "Some \(value) with %@ special \n characters"
```

**EDIT**

Although @RavinderSingh13's answer did not match expected output, it was close and I used it to modify my command like so:

```
BEGIN { old=ARGV[1]; new=ARGV[2]; ARGV[1]=ARGV[2]=""; len=length(old) }
s=index($0,old) { if (!(match($0,/.*\/\//))) $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+len) }
{ print }' "$old" "$new" "$file"
```

This meets the original requirement, but ignores ANY line that has two slashes. This is problematic, because it doesn't support in line comments (e.g. the above command would not edit any of the sample input; unless the "// <-- This should change" comment is removed. If no one replies, I'll use this as the answer, but I'll wait a day or so in case someone posts a version of the command that meets all the requirements. Will accept that answer.

It would be something like this...

```
s=index($0,old) { if (!(match($0,/.*\/\//)) || (match($0,/"$old".*\/\//))) $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+len) }
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Also do you mean that you don't want to get values after `//` in a line,could you please confirm that please.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, yes I don't want to change the value if it's to the right of the slashes (commented out) but I do want to change it if it's  to the left of the slashes (not commented out).

Comment: @Cyrus I've just added some sample input / output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only look for "old" in the part of each line before the start of any comment, e.g.:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { old=ARGV[1]; new=ARGV[2]; ARGV[1]=ARGV[2]=""; len=length(old) }
    { preCmt = $0; sub("//.*","", preCmt) }
    s=index(preCmt,old) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+len) }
    { print }
' "$old" "$new" file
    /// - Returns: "Some \(value) with %@ special \n characters"
    static let someValue = "some_key".localized // <-- This should change

    static let otherValue = "This line does NOT change" // "Some \(value) with %@ special \n characters
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you want skip all lines which start from `//` and also you want to print contents which comes before `//` for in between inline comments. Fair warning not tested since NO samples given.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { old=ARGV[1]; new=ARGV[2]; ARGV[1]=ARGV[2]=""; len=length(old) }
    /^\/\//{ next }
    match($0,/.*\/\//){ $0 = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-2) }
    s=index($0,old) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+len) }
    { print }
' "$old" "$new" "$file" > ./temp
```

---

---

Above will neglect lines which are starting with `//` if you want to print them then do following.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { old=ARGV[1]; new=ARGV[2]; ARGV[1]=ARGV[2]=""; len=length(old) }
    /^\/\//{ print; next }
    match($0,/.*\/\//){ $0 = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-2) }
    s=index($0,old) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+len) }
    { print }
' "$old" "$new" "$file" > ./temp
```